# F# Custom Operators Precedence

Tags: f#, operators

In F#, you can define custom operators like

```
let (=~) input pattern = Regex.IsMatch(input, pattern)
```

Unlike Haskell, custom operators are defined without precedences.
What are the operator precedences of the custom operators in F#?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Operator precedence is determined by the first character(s), according to a [predefined table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233228.aspx#Anchor_1).

Comment: See also the F# spec: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html#_Toc264041843

Comment: Couldn't find the precedence of operators starting with '@', but it's possible to define such operators, the format being `@<op>`.

Comment: From the source cited by the answer: "F# supports custom operator overloading. This means that you can define your own operators. In the previous table, op can be any valid (possibly empty) sequence of operator characters, either built-in or user-defined. Thus, you can use this table to determine what sequence of characters to use for a custom operator to achieve the desired level of precedence."