# Error: Unexpected infix operator in expression, about a successfully compiled prefix operator

Tags: f#, operator-overloading, prefix-operator, infix-operator

Playing around a little bit with infix operators, I was surprised about the following:

```
let (>~~~) = function null -> String.Empty | s -> s  // compiles fine, see screenshot
match >~~~ input with .... // error: Unexpected infix operator in expression
```

[image: val (>~~~) : string -> string)]

and:

[image: Unexpected infix operator]

Changing the first characters of the *prefix* operator (to `!~~~` for instance) fixes it. That I get an error that the *infix* operator is unexpected is rather weird. Hovering shows the definition to be `string -> string`.

I'm not too surprised about the error, F# requires (iirc) that the first character of a prefix operator must itself be one of the predefined prefix operators. But why does it compile just fine, and when I use it, the compiler complains?

Update: the F# compiler seems to know in other cases just fine when I use an invalid character in my operator definition, it says *"Invalid operator definition. Prefix operator definitions must use a valid prefix operator name."*

[image: Invalid operator definition.]

Comment: what if you put `>~~~` inside parantheses in the match expression as well?

Comment: @s952163: simple, but yeah, that works. But it defeats a bit of the grand idea of creating an operator in the first place, if you have to add parentheses.

Comment: yes... unfortunately. And I have no idea why. It is a very interesting case indeed.

Comment: In F# [brackets are used to control precedence](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39296035/126014), and precedence of custom operators is [controlled by a pre-defined table](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3348031/126014). So `>` has difference precedence than `!`.

Comment: This occurs in other cases as well: e.g. `let (~+.) x = -x` and
`(~+.)  5` will give you -5 but only with the parantheses....pretty arcane stuff...

Comment: @MarkSeemann, I know, but that doesn't explain why you need parentheses here. There is no precedence that needs to be changed. And if you use the same operator without parens in an infix definition, it just works without them.

Comment: @s952163 Given `let (~+.) x = -x`, you can actually write `+. 10`. The `~` symbol is used to distinguish between binary operators starting with `+` and unary operators starting with `+`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rules for custom operators in F# are quite tight - so even though you can define custom operators, there is a lot of rules about how they will behave and you cannot change those. In particular:

- Only some operators (mainly those with `!` and `~`) can be used as prefix operators. With `~` you can also overload unary operators `+`, `-`, `~` and `~~`, so if you define an operator named `~+.`, you can then use it as e.g. `+. 42`.
- Other operators (including those starting with `>`) can only be used as infix. You can turn any operator into ordinary function using parentheses, which is why e.g. `(+) 1 2` is valid.
- The `?` symbols is special (it is used for dynamic invocation) and cannot appear as the first symbol of a custom operator.

I think the most intuitive way of thinking about this is that custom operators will behave like standard F# operators, but you can add additional symbols after the standard operator name.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I am aware of those rules, but as can be seen, these rules can be bent (you can define a postfix operator with an infix operator first character, as long as you use parens in the call). And the error talks about an infix operator, but doesn't complain about the declaration. Why is something like `let (>~) = function null -> true | _ -> false` not illegal then?

Comment: @Abel It is not illegal because you can still use it via parentheses (this is not bending the rules, but treating operator as an ordinary function). It is also probably not illegal because you could have generic operator of type `int -> 'a` which can either be unary or binary, depending on the generic instantiation - so saying what is unary function is not that easy in F#.